# What is the best way to retrieve profiles from a Salesforce org?

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, profile, customsetting

PS: There are other questions with the same subject line, but the question is different. Please don't mark it as duplicate.

It seems to retrieve the entire profile definition, we need to retrieve visualforce pages, tabs, apex classes, custom objects and many other things.

How can we retrieve the full profile definition without retrieving everything?

Answer (score 1):

That's the nature of the Metadata API, per Usage section found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm).

> ### Usage
>
> When you use the retrieve() call to get information about profiles in your organization, the returned .profile files only include security settings for the other metadata types referenced in the retrieve request (with the exception of user permissions, IP address ranges, and login hours, which are always retrieved).